# How to inherit custom javascript from parent to child pages?

Tags: javascript

I have a function I wish to use in 10 different javascript files (each are used on a different webpage). I was hoping to avoid copying/pasting the function into every .js file.

The pages all have the **same parent page**.

Is there a way I can define this function once and call it from each page's .js file?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes this should be easy to do. How are you including the current per-page script files though - with wp_enqueue_script, per page or template name? That should be easy to extend to include the parent page's script too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the function in its own separate JS file, and load that file alongside the page-specific files. The "WordPress way" would be to register the script containing the shared function(s) and then set it as a dependency of the other scripts:

```
wp_register_script( 'my-functions', get_theme_file_uri( 'js/functions.js' ) );

if ( is_page( 1 ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-page-1', get_theme_file_uri( 'js/page-1.js' ), [ 'my-functions' ] );
}

if ( is_page( 2 ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-page-2', get_theme_file_uri( 'js/page-2.js' ), [ 'my-functions' ] );
}

// etc.
```

Comment: Great, thank you! 1 quick question - why is not necessary to register the 'my-page-1' script? Or did you leave that out for simplicity? Cheers

Comment: If you enqueue a script that's not already registered it will be automatically registered. Registering the first script was necessary because we needed to use it as a dependency. You'd also register, rather than enqueue, if the logic for enqueuing existed in multiple places and you didn't want to have to repeat the path each time.